# How do I select an entire column from a range?

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I am trying to identify all the cells in a column that have the following and change the font color to red.

- a space
- a hyphen
- an underscore
- more than 16 characters in a cell

This is my code

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
   // Get the active worksheet 


  let sheet : ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  // Get the range for column A
  let range = sheet.getRange("A:A");  

  // Get the values for the range
  let values = range.getValues();

  // Check for null values
  if (values.length !== null) 
  {    // Loop through the values and check for conditions
    for (let row = 0; row < values.length; row++) 
    {
      let cellValue = values[row][0].toString();
      if(cellValue.length>16)
      {
        sheet.getRange(`A${row + 1}`).getFormat().getFont().setColor("Red");        
      }
      if(cellValue.includes(" "))
      {
        sheet.getRange(`A${row + 1}`).getFormat().getFont().setColor("Red");
      }
      if (cellValue.includes("-")) 
      {
        sheet.getRange(`A${row + 1}`).getFormat().getFont().setColor("Red");
      }
      if (cellValue.includes("_")) 
      {
        sheet.getRange(`A${row + 1}`).getFormat().getFont().setColor("Red");
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

When I run this script I get the following error.

Line 13: Can't read properties of null (reading 'length');

My Excel : Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20378) 64-bit

I didn't understand where I made a mistake as I used the getRange line from the row and column visibility example [in this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples). Looking for an answer I came across another way to select an entire column and made the the following changes. This got the script running perfectly.

```
let range = sheet.getUsedRange();
range.getColumn(0);
```

I still haven't found an answer to my initial error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you use a whole column reference (e.g. `A:A`) and try to get the `values`of that range, it returns null. e.g.:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active worksheet 

    let sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the range for column A
    let range = sheet.getRange("A:A")

    // Get the values for the range
    let values = range.getValues();
    console.log(values) //returns null
}
```

One alternative is to try to select the `getExtendedRange` method with the `down` argument to get the whole range of the column. So you could update your range variable to look like this:

```js
let range = sheet.getRange("A1").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down)
```

Another is to add `getUsedRange` to your original `A:A` range reference like so:

```js
let range = sheet.getRange("A:A").getUsedRange();
```

Comment: I knew there was something more to that statement that I was missing. Both of your suggestions worked perfectly.

Thank you very much!!